# How to return a list objects in a many2one field

Tags: python, odoo-11

I have declared a many2one field

```
packaging_id = fields.Many2one(
        'product.packaging', 'Package type', compute='_compute_package_type',
        index=True)
```

So I need to make a logic to return what objects I want to show in the  list. I have tried it using a compute option but I am not sure this is correct. Follow my compute field

```
@api.multi
    def _compute_package_type(self):
        pckdel = self.batch_id.package_delivery_group
        order = self.env['ord.data'].search([("pckdelgrp", "=", pckdel)], limit=1)
        type = self.env['delivery.carrier'].search([("name", "=", order.deliverymethod)], limit=1)
        if type.delivery_type == 'test' or type.delivery_type == 'xxx':
            package_objs = self.env['product.packaging'].sudo().search([])
        else:
            package_objs = self.env['product.packaging'].search([("packager_carrier_type", "=", type.delivery_type)])
        self.packaging_id =  package_objs.ids
```

However it fails and does  not appear the dropdown list with the  package_objs. Could someone please help me on that?

THANK U SO MUCH

Answer (score 1):

In This type of scenario you should use `domain` instead on `compute`

```
def compute_package_type(self):
            pckdel = self.batch_id.package_delivery_group
            order = self.env['ord.data'].search([("pckdelgrp", "=", pckdel)], limit=1)
            type = self.env['delivery.carrier'].search([("name", "=", order.deliverymethod)], limit=1)
            if type.delivery_type == 'test' or type.delivery_type == 'xxx':
                package_objs = self.env['product.packaging'].sudo().search([])
            else:
                package_objs = self.env['product.packaging'].search([("packager_carrier_type", "=", type.delivery_type)])
            return [('id','in',package_objs.ids)]


packaging_id = fields.Many2one(
        'product.packaging', 'Package type', domain=compute_package_type)
```

Comment: Hello Pruthvi 
          Thank you so much for your quickly response. However when I try that I received the error 

          field '_compute_package_type' used in attributes must be present in view but is missing:
 - '_compute_package_type' in domain='_compute_package_type'

Comment: Hello, I edited my answer please check. Define function on the field declaration

Comment: Nice Pruthvi Thank you so much again!!! It worked  perfect but only once I would like to have this method and then the domain 'computed" every time that I try to open the drop down list. Do u think  that is possible?

Comment: Yes that's possible if we do this logic on some dependent field's `onchange` this will return domain every time that field changed. Otherwise this will work for you if your matching criteria not changing every time when you open dropdown. If matching criteria is fixed that this solution is best because of every new record use should match only once at the time of opening that record. If your matching criteria is changing based on other field's values than tell me.